# Where i get a documentation for metro ui design

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am going to start designing web page using **metro ui**. I need a good documentation for the metro ui like that of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers an [Index of UX Guidlines for Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx), which would be a good place to start.  This covers everything from touch interaction to charms usages and everything in between.

Comment: Your link is really use full. The problem am facing is that i cannot use the grid system or the background classes correctly. The css and javascript files are included properly. it will be more helpful if there is any template available for reference.